# Lambda expressions in attribute

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, lambda

I have a static class called Mod with a static function called Map:

```
public static class Mod<TModel>
{
    public static string Map<TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not implemented");
    }
}
```

I can execute the method like this (with no problem):

```
var test = Mod<string>.Map<string>(x => x.ToLower());
```

I have an attribute with a string param on its constructor:

```
public class MyTestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyTestAttribute(string label)
    {

    }
}
```

Why can't I call it like this?

```
[Attributes.MyTest(Attributes.Mod<string>.Map<string>(x => x.ToLower()))]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

I get the error "expression cannot contain anonymous methods or lambda expressions". But why?

I am well aware lambda expressions won't work in attributes... but why won't a static class/static method with a lambda work as a param to an attribute (...if that's the problem I am experiencing)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the value that you are passing to Attribute's constructor should be compile time constant.And the result of your method is not a constant because it is not known at compile time.So this is not actually specific to lambda expressions, it can only be one of these as explained in error message:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type